# Double Integral of exponential with trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How can one perform the integration?
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \int_0^\lambda d\rho\,\rho\, e^{-\rho^2(sin^2\phi + \frac{\beta}{\lambda}\cos^2\phi )}$$

Comment: The question boils down to computing integral of the form $\int e^{a x}I_0(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$, where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. I am not sure if this can be done, though.

Comment: The $\rho$ integral is trivial,  leaving a difficult integral over $\phi$.